# Transfer time from JFK to EWR

Tags: transit, taxis, jfk, ewr

I'm flying into JFK on Cathay Pacific, then onto Ithaca, NY from Newark International on United. Can anyone advise the transit time via taxi from JFK to Newark Int'l? Will traffic be an issue driving through Manhattan to Newark?

I get into JFK at 13:10 and my flight at Newark is 17:15.

Comment: Um, yes. Traffic can be a considerable issue, depending on the day of the week and time of day. How much time do you have between flights?

Comment: Really need to tell us how much time you have between your flights... also US immigration can sometimes take a long time, although my 2 times at Newark have been pleasant compared to other airports... maybe because less international flights arrive. A taxi would also cost a lot of money if you use a yellow cab, there are shuttle buses and train that will be a lot cheaper.

Comment: Do you need to go through Manhattan? Google Maps suggests that the fastest route (right now, this might depend on the time of the day) leads via Staten Island.

Comment: I get into JFK at 1310 and my flight at Newark is 17:15.

Comment: Of related interest: *[Options for JFK to EWR transfer](/q/58282)*, *[How to transfer from JFK to Newark using public transportation?](/q/42797)*

Comment: Just to give you an idea of how much traffic can change things, Google Maps gives time ranges for the drive (just the drive, not all the other steps) as between 1:20 and 2:40 around that time of day (it's around 40-50 minutes with no traffic). You might also consider taking the bus up to Ithaca from Manhattan if the flight doesn't work. You have [several](https://web.coachusa.com/shortline/index.asp?nt=0) different [bus](http://bigredbullet.com/) options [available](https://ipp.cornell.edu/content/campus-campus-bus-service) (possibly others I'm not aware of as well).

Comment: You could also see about getting on the 8:30 flight to Ithaca instead, which would give you more time. That's the last flight out for the night though, so you run the risk of being stuck in New York if it's cancelled or you don't make it.

Comment: [C2C](https://ipp.cornell.edu/content/campus-campus-bus-service) FTW

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look good.

From landing to take-off, you need to:

1. Leave the airport (get off the plane, immigration, pick up luggage) - will probably take between 30 minutes and an hour, but may be significantly more.
2. Wait for a taxi. With some luck it's no time, but you never know.
3. Drive to Newark - according to [Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/jfk/newark/@40.7292155,-74.1353389,11z/am=t/data=!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c26650d5404947:0xec4fb213489f11f0!2m2!1d-73.7781391!2d40.6413111!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c252e1c5ec0cef:0xb3f3b437c5d7f286!2m2!1d-74.1744624!2d40.6895314!2m3!6e1!7e2!8j1498838400!3e0?hl=en) driving time is 1:20 hours.
4. Arrive at the airport 1:30 hours before take-off.

This adds up to at least 3:20 hours, while you have 4:05. So you might make it. But a delay in any of these stages will easily make you miss your flight.

What can go wrong? Your flight to JFK may delay, long lines at immigration or security, bad traffic and more.

Your willingness to risk it highly depends on whether your flights are booked as one or two tickets. If it's one ticket, and you miss your connection, the airline will take care of you. If it's two tickets, then it's your responsibility to show up on time, and you'll need to buy a new ticket from Newark to Ithaca.

Comment: Hour and a half to cross Manhattan?  I don't believe that.  Took me two hours to cross Manhattan at ten AM in July 1976.  Walking would have been faster, but the job required the pickup truck.

Comment: @WGroleau, If it takes so long to cross Manhattan, just don't. Google's suggested path crosses from Brooklyn to Staten Island over the Verrazano Narrows Bridge.

Comment: Ah, OK.  Someone else said crossing Manhattan.  Sorry.

Comment: @WGroleau, it was actually the OP who assumed in the question that he needs to cross Manhattan.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able-bodied, not a lot of baggage and no kids, then with careful timing you should make it. I would advice taking the public transportation:

1. Airtrain to Jamaica
2. LIRR to Penn Station
3. NJ Transit/Amtrak to EWR

Google shows 1:20 - 1:40 for the whole ordeal, and you would not depend on any traffic.

To speed things up I would do the following:

1. Have a smartphone with [LIRR e-ticketing app](http://www.mta.info/mta-eTix-promo) and purchase a ticket while on AirTrain.
2. Have spare change to pay for AirTrain exit fare (or get a MetroCard in advance)
3. Have [NJTransit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njtransit.njtapp&hl=en) and [Amtrak](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amtrak.rider&hl=en) apps available, and see schedule/buy the ticket while on LIRR.

NB. Amtrak/NJTransit/LIRR are doing some repairs on the Penn Station after a series of recent derailments. Watch their respective websites for schedule changes.

Comment: Regarding #2, you must buy/have a MetroCard to exit the AirTrain system at JFK. The turnstiles to exit do not accept cash or change. (There are machines at the exit so you can buy your MetroCard. The machines accept cash.)